# seqret: Warning: bad /protein_id value

Tags: file-formats, format-conversion, gtf, emboss, seqret

I am using the seqret tool from the Emboss suite to transform produce an EMBL annotation file from a GTF annotation file and the corresponding FASTA sequence:

```
seqret -sequence ecoli.fa -feature -fformat gff -fopenfile ecoli.gtf -osformat embl -auto -outseq ecoli.embl
```

It produces my desired EMBL file but it warns against a 'bad protein_id':

```
...
Warning: bad /protein_id value '"CCE57732"'
Warning: bad /protein_id value '"CCE57733"'
Warning: bad /protein_id value '"CCE57734"'
Warning: bad /protein_id value '"CCE57735"'
Warning: bad /protein_id value '"CCE57754"'
```

What's wrong with these protein IDs? The organism I am working with is *Escherichia coli*.

Here are a few lines from my GTF file. The first line has a protein_id.

```
Chromosome      ena     CDS     349     2808    .       +       0       gene_id "HUS2011_0001"; transcript_id "CCQ26880"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "thrA"; gene_source "ena"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "thrA-1"; transcript_source "ena"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "CCQ26880";
Chromosome      ena     start_codon     349     351     .       +       0       gene_id "HUS2011_0001"; transcript_id "CCQ26880"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "thrA"; gene_source "ena"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "thrA-1"; transcript_source "ena"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
Chromosome      ena     stop_codon      2809    2811    .       +       0       gene_id "HUS2011_0001"; transcript_id "CCQ26880"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "thrA"; gene_source "ena"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "thrA-1"; transcript_source "ena"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
```

Comment: To me it looks like a bug, where the encoding or the quotes are not properly handled. (ie, CCE57754 would be a valid protien_id(?) but "CCE57754" it isn't)

Comment: Can you show (a small part of) your GTF file? I tend to agree with Llopis, but not all fields in the GTF files can be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You're supplying a GTF feature file, but telling it that the features are in GFF3 format. I think you need `-fformat gff2`. See https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/sfc/emboss_seqret/help/

Comment: I tried with gff2 but I get the same problem: Warning: bad /protein_id value 'CCQ26880'
Warning: bad /protein_id value 'CCQ26881'
Warning: bad /protein_id value 'CCQ26882'
Warning: bad /protein_id value 'CCQ26883'

Comment: If your copying the output directly, that's a different problem ('CCQ26880' vs. '''CCQ26880"'). It looks like it's parsing the GTF correctly but choking on the values for some reason. I'm not very familiar with this tool so I can't  advise further.

Comment: Do you use another tool to get EMBL files from GTF and FASTA?

Comment: @charlesdarwin have you tried this to convert FASTA -> EMBL? http://sequenceconversion.bugaco.com/converter/biology/sequences/embl_to_fasta.php (no idea of how it works, but you can try)